# What does ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitize

Will `sanitize` deal with sql injection?

From its source code: (extracted from [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/Base/sanitize/class))

```
  def sanitize(object) #:nodoc:
    connection.quote(object)
  end
```

`sanitize` uses `quote, whose source code (extracted from [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/quote)) is:

```
  def quote(value, column = nil)
    self.class.connection.quote(value, column)
  end
```

I'm confused, it seems `sanitize` only adds quote for input, but when we are dealing with sql injection, shouldn't we do much more things like eliminating potential SQL query? What does it do and can it really SANITIZE input before executing sql query?

Comment: ActiveRecord sanitization does handle SQL injection. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: Something like `'Robert''); drop table students'` – note the doubled (i.e. quoted) single quote – is just a string literal, there's no danger of it being interpreted as SQL (unless your database is broken beyond belief of course). Proper quoting *does* eliminate SQL injection.